# Requesting HTTP POST with a Kendo Grid custom toolbar

Tags: kendo-grid

How can I have a POST request for my custom toolbar?

Is custom Ajax request the only way to achieve this?

This is my toolbar:

```
toolbar.Excel();
toolbar.Pdf();
toolbar.Custom().Text("ex").Action("ex", "controller");
toolbar.Save().CancelText(" ").SaveText(" ");
```

Comment: Like create? What's on your toolbar? Can you post some code please?

Comment: No, I don't want a create button on this toolbar. The action doesn't return anything, or maybe just a `Boolean`.

Comment: Can't find a way to configure HttpPost, seems to be doing a Get by default. Think you'll need to do a custom $.Ajax call. :(

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort Vash. :)